# librdkafka custom logger, function signature

Tags: c++, logging, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I'm using the librdkafka c++ API and I would like to change the default behavior of the logger.

In the c API there is this function `rd_kafka_conf_set_log_cb()` to set the log callback. It takes a function with the signature:

```
void(*)(const rd_kafka_t *rk, int level, const char *fac, const char *buf)
```

However I can't figure out what const char *fac does in the function signature. I can see that strings such as "FAIL" or "BGQUEUE" are passed when using it, but I can't find any documentation on what they mean or how to use them.

What is the `const char *fac` used for, and are there docs on its use or a dictionary for their definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facility string is a semi-unique name for the context where the log is emitted. It is mainly there to help librdkafka maintainers identify the source of a log line, but can also be used for filtering purposes.

It was originally inspired by [Cisco IOS like system logs](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/wireless/software/guide/SysMsgLogging.html#wp1054485) which came in the form of:

`FAC-LVL-SUBFAC: Message...`

The librdkafka counterpart would be:

`RDKAFKA-7-JOIN: Joining consumer group xyx`

where JOIN is the librdkafka logging facility.